# Получить подкатегории всех уровней у категории

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Ребята, такой вопрос. Я с рекурсией не очень дружу. Никак не могу реализовать следующее.

У меня такая структура БД категорий:

`id | name | parent_id` - т.е. ничего особенного.

Нужно получить одномерный массив всех подкатегорий, которые есть у категории.
Например, у категории 20 есть подкатегории 21,22,23. У них тоже есть подкатегории. Вот все эти ветки нужно слить в один одномерный массив и вернуть.

Может кто подскажет, каким образом можно рекурсивно все это получить? Буду благодарен за помощь и советы.

Comment: Приветствую! Думаю будет недостаточно дать здесь просто ответ - понимание не придет. Поэтому поделюсь ссылкой на Хабр: [Рекурсивные запросы](http://habrahabr.ru/post/27439/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Вариант без рекурсии - массив собирается PHP-скриптом.** Выбираем все обычным селектом в SQL:

```
$mysql = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$result = $mysql->query('SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM categories;');
```

Выбираются **все данные**. И по этому массиву потом проходим при помощи PHP:

```
$arr = array();
while ($i = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arr[$i['parent_id']][] = $i['id'];
}
```

Если помимо ключей нужно ещё и имя, то массив станет многомерным:

```
while ($i = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arr[$i['parent_id']][$i['id']] = $i['name'];
}
```

Обычно категорий немного, чтобы делать выборку конкретно под ID категории. А вот если их реально много-премного, тогда да, без рекурсии не обойтись.

UPD1. Добавим выборку по ID категории (опять же в PHP):

```
$arr  = array(); // результирующий массив
$keys = array(); // здесь будет массив ключей
$keys[] = $category; // добавляем первый ключ в массив

while ($i = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  // Проверяем наличие ID категории в массиве ключей
  if (in_array($i['parent_id'], $keys)) {
    $arr[$i['parent_id']][] = $i['id'];
    $keys[] = $i['id']; // расширяем массив
  }
}
```

UPD2. Возвращаем массив вида *array(5,6,7,8,9)* - это массив *$keys* из примера выше после выполнения цикла. Просто уберите строку *$arr[$i['parent_id']][] = $i['id'];*

Comment: Спасибо, но не очень понял как применить.

Вот у меня категория 20. У нее есть несколько подкатегорий у которых так же есть подкатегории.

Так то мне возвращает массив\ы, но не так как нужно.

Мне нужно по id категории, вытащить ее подкатегории + все подкатегории подкатегорий.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Приведите пример, как должен выглядеть ваш результирующий массив. И было бы вообще хорошо, если были бы демонстрационные данные, допустим с тремя-четырьмя уровнями зависимости. Если данные приватные и вам не хочется их светить, возьмите [тезаурус Баранова](http://thesaurus1.narod.ru/).

Comment: Сделал пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5a09

Есть я делаю выборку по категории 5, то вернуть должно массив вида array(5,6,7,8,9);

Т.е. id всех подкатегорий у категории 5 и подкатегорий подкатегорий.

Вот категории 8 и 9 являются подкатегориями 6, а категория 6 является подкатегорией 5. Т.е. все уровки какие могут быть, нужно в одномерный массив загнать.

Comment: Забавно, ответ уже был готов - это массив $keys

Comment: Да. Большое, @Khvorostin, Вам спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysql = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$arr = array();
function tree($id)
{
    $result = $mysql->query('SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '.(int)$id);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        // тут обрабатываем очередной лист
        $arr[] = $row['id']; // добавляем в одномерный массив
        tree($row['id']); // тут обрабатываем все дочерние элементы у row['id']
    }
}

tree(20); // запускаем рекурсию
```

вот, немного набросал, сам не тестил, но должно работать, и идея должна быть понятна :)