# Вывод всех подкатегорий основной категории

Tags: php, mysql, меню

Есть БД Mysql и таблица категорий cats:

```
id|father|title
1 |0     |Фрукты
2 |0     |Овощи
3 |1     |Яблоки
4 |3     |Красные
5 |3     |Зеленые
```

Какой самый оптимальный способ, при выборе допустим категории (1|0|Фрукты) показать всех его сыновей ( 3|1|Яблоки, 4|3|Красные, 5|3|Зеленые ), если учесть что у самих сыновей может быть много своих сыновей, допустим 100 штук.

Comment: Какая версия MySQL ? В 8 есть рекурсивный CTE, в предыдущих версиях все грустно и там жуткие извращения на тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634545/194569

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить подкатегории всех уровней у категории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/225501/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Вообщем, все зависит от задачи, если просто обычный сбор в кучу, то можно и `left join`ом обыграть, а если надо делать дерево, то тут только делать либо рекурсию, либо циклами и массивами обходить.

Comment: Рекомендую внимательнейшим образом ознакомиться по Вашей проблеме: [Деревья в SQL](http://gsbelarus.com/pw/articles/post/derev-ia-v-sql/)

Answer (score -1):

Предложенные варианты не подошли, однако они помогли мне выработать свой простой способ решить вопрос. Это функция, принимает уже проверенное значение ($_get_safe_id) существующей категории и формирует строку из (id) всех ее сыновей и сыновей сыновей и т.д. Ко всему этому присоединяется проверяемый родитель. В итоге получаем список значений всех возможных подкатегорий основной родительской категории, который потом вставляем в оператор IN().

```
// iamfather
$_iamfather_result = '';
function dynmenu_iamfather($_data)
{
//
global $_db_connect;
global $_iamfather_result;
//
if ( !empty($_data)) {
$_db_cats_find = $_db_connect->query(" SELECT cats.id AS cats_id FROM cats WHERE cats.sid = '$_data' AND cats.allow = 1 ");
//
if ( $_db_cats_find->num_rows >= 1 ) {
while ($_db_cats_find_result = $_db_cats_find->fetch_assoc()) {
$_db_cats_find_result_cats_id = $_db_cats_find_result['cats_id'];
$_iamfather_result .= $_db_cats_find_result_cats_id.',';
//
if (!empty($_db_cats_find_result_cats_id))
{ dynmenu_iamfather($_db_cats_find_result_cats_id); }}}}
return $_iamfather_result;
}

//
$_get_safe_id = 2;
//
dynmenu_iamfather($_get_safe_id).$_get_safe_id;
// out-> 1,2,...,52,2
```

Comment: Если вам, нужно выводить только потомков, это лучше сделать через `left join`, а не городить огород и изобретать велосипед. 1 запрос и вывод построчно, избавит от постоянной выборки категории и ее потомков.